# How to edit an a tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using a CMS that does not allow lots of edit options for menus and here is what the HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li><a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google">Go</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to change the `a` tag  by adding this attribute:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Download form', eventAction: 'Click'});"
```

The result should look like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li><a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Menu-Button', eventAction: 'Click'});">Go</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can't use `getElementById`, class or name as this is not the only `a` tag inside a list. Any thoughts?

Comment: simply use attr, $('a[href=""]).attr('onclick', 'value'); but it might not w

Comment: What happened to `href="rsvp-form.pdf"`?

Comment: I just noticed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

> this is not the only a tag inside a list

Sorry, just seen this and corrected the answer to apply to all `a` tags with such `href` attribute

With raw javascript: [**JS Fiddle 1**-*updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/t8fc4jbL/)

```js
var linkHTML = "<a href=\"http://example.org?utm_source=google\" onclick=\"ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Menu-Button', eventAction: 'Click'});\">Go</a>";
var links = document.querySelectorAll('li a[href="http://example.org?utm_source=google"]');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].outerHTML = linkHTML;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google">Go</a>
  </li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google">Go</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

With jQuery [**JS Fiddle 2**-*updated*](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/tp0jr2k4/4/)

```js
var linkHTML = "<a href=\"http://example.org?utm_source=google\" onclick=\"ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Menu-Button', eventAction: 'Click'});\">Go</a>";

$('li a[href="http://example.org?utm_source=google"]').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().html(linkHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google">Go</a>
  </li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li><a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google">Go</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### ----------

Output:

> ```
> <li>
>   <a href="http://example.org?utm_source=google" onclick="ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 'Menu-Button', eventAction: 'Click'});">Go</a>
> </li>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job. Now I have to figure out a way to add an attribute to a tag without having to rewrite the whole tag (eg. adding an onclick attribute without deleting others).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you can use any attribute present in the tags to uniquely identify the elements? Just for an example, I can uniquely find your a tag with `href=http://example.org?utm_source=google` with the below selector
`a[href=http://example.org?utm_source=google]`.

Will something like that can be done in your case?

If the above works and jQuery can be used in the code, we can simply associate the event with it in the usual way like:

```
$('a[href=http://example.org?utm_source=google]').click(function () {
    /*Your Code here*/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju3vLgno/)

Since the anchor tag is in the last element of the `ul`, you can use `:last-child` selector. See the JS below

```
$('ul li:last>a').attr('onclick',"ga('send', 'event', { eventCategory: 
  'Menu-Button', eventAction: 'Click'});");
```

Please see the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) to read more about `last-child` selector.

And, here is a screenshot for ready reference

[image]

Comment: Why setting `onclick` with `attr()` O.o `$(...).on("click", function() { ga(...); })`

Comment: Only because the OP wants that :D..He has specifically mentioned in his question that he wants the output to be like that.. ;) @Andreas

Comment: Try this answer @loan

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it myself in jsfiddle and it works. How about if I can't use jQuery? Is there a way to add an attribute to a tag using only javascript?